# gow to get Highcharts solid Gauge data from a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i'm new in JS and highcharts.
I'm trying to get the solid Gauge data value from a simple item list.
But it doesn't seem to work. The list is an AJAX response[].
Apparently the value must be inserted between '[]' still no data displayed. 
what's the problem in my code?

```
var value = '['+response[0]+']';

        $('#rquest').append(response[0]);
        $('#response').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'gauge',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBackgroundImage: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            pane: {
                startAngle: -150,
                endAngle: 150

            },
            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                minorTickWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 10,
                minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                minorTickColor: '#666',
                tickPixelInterval: 30,
                tickWidth: 2,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickLength: 10,
                tickColor: '#666',
                labels: {
                    step: 2,
                    rotation: 'auto'
                },
                title: {
                    text: '%'
                },
                plotBands: [{
                        from: 0,
                        to: 30,
                        color: '#DF5353' // red
                    }, {
                        from: 30,
                        to: 60,
                        color: '#55BF3B' // yellow
                    }, {
                        from: 60,
                        to: 100,
                        color: '#DF5353' // red
                    }]
            },
            series: [{
                    name: 'Speed',
                    data: value,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                    }
                }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your `value` variable is `string` and from my point of view the value passes to the `series.data` should be a real array.

You can transform a "array-like" string to an array like below (assume your `response[0]` is like `"a,b,c"`):

```
var value = response[0].split(',');
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, I suggest that you put more code, like what exactly `response[0]` is and what is printed in the `console`...